# character device permission issues

Tags: linux, bash, device

I want to be able to write directly to a character device. Here's what I do:

```
cd /dev
mknod moo c 0 0
echo hello >> moo
```

I get

```
bash: moo: Permission denied
```

I tried using chmod to give the owning user write access like so:

```
chmod 777 moo
```

Then when I tried writing to it I was informed that the device or address does not exist. ls informs me otherwise.

Also worth noting is that as far as I know giving 0 0 as the major minor number pair causes Linux to just give the device something convenient.

I must be missing something fundamental here, I thought device nodes could be treated as normal files. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Ideally I would like to make a character device node that the owner can write to and anyone can read from (I know 777 is the wrong permission here, I'll fix that in the final version).

I also (initially) tried talking to it via Python and that gave me the same issues.

EDIT:

0 0 was the wrong thing to do. I read a thing once that told me it would work, it lied. What I need to do is make a character device module and a node to match then use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All devices have specific major and minor numbers defined in drivers. You cannot set it to whatever you want, and `0 0` looks severely invalid. You have to come up with valid ones, and maybe then you'll succeed.

The major and minor numbers tie the node entry to a specific driver. And no, the `/dev/*` files are not like any others. They are special because the kernels redirects the input/output/control operations to specific driver routines.

Comment: So besides the part about 0 0 (i edited the Q, it should be fine to say that unless the documentation I have been reading is dead wrong) what you are saying is that I need to make a module to deal with the char device? I know the pair ties to a module, but is a module strictly necesssary if all I want it to do is look like a character device?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure of the 0 0 major/minor device identifiers ?

As [explained here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2),

- major number (the first 0 in your command) is the identifier of the driver you want to use for your device.
- minor number (the second 0 in your command) is the identifier of the device managed by the driver referenced by the major code.

What I called driver, is a driver as seen by the kernel.

What you're trying to do in your example is to create a device without any driver behind... it will not work (as you already experienced ;) ).

Why do you need a character device ? According to your need (one writer, multiple readers) you could use a named pipe with [mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) or even standard files ;)

Comment: putting in the 0 0 should make Linux pick a suitable pair for me as far as I know. The reason I want to make a character device is because I want to replace one, /dev/random specifically. I have a little RNG that chats with my PC via USB using a simple CDC driver. I thought that was a win because using this diver would mean that I could use a daemon instead of a kernal module which means (for me) writing in Python rather than C. That's the short version. If using a fifo wont alter the requirements of any program expecting a character device in any way then this is great. I'll check it out